# Mongonaut error: 'Mongonaut does not work with models which have fields beginning with id_'

Tags: python, django, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I'm using the following combination of packages to work with mongodb in Django.

```
django-mongonaut==0.2.21
mongoengine==0.8.7
pymongo==2.7.2
```

I'm trying to set up my admin panel using mongonaut.
These are my two simple mongo engine models:

```
class Question(Document):
    text = StringField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class QuestionList(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=200)
    questions = EmbeddedDocumentField('Question') #This is the problem

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Currently I'm not using a ListField yet. When I try to add a new QuestionList using Mongonaut the following error pops up:

```
KeyError at /mongonaut/api/QuestionList/add/
u'Mongonaut does not work with models which have fields beginning with id_'
```

The mongonaut docs state that it allows working with EmbeddedDocumentFields. Still I get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Swen